# Regex for extracting text after a specific word between quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some strings that have a format like this:

```
"text that comes before\"start\":\"Desired Info\"text that comes after"
```

I'd like to extract only "Desired Info".  It will always be preceded by `"\"start\":"` and this will only appear once in the string. What regex can I use to do this?

Comment: It may be clearer if you presented the string without all the escapes by enclosing it in single quotes: `'text that comes before"start":"Desired Info"text that comes after'
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shall work:

```
s = "text that comes before\"start\":\"Desired Info\"text that comes after"

s[/(?<="start":")[^"]*(?=")/]
# => "Desired Info"
```

Comment: I'm curious about what the `.` is for.

Comment: @pguardiario That was not necessary. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Here: is the regular expression:

```
"start":"(.*)"
```

In code:

```
match = /"start":(.*)"/.match("text that comes before\"start\":\"Desired Info\"text that comes after");

if match
    print match[1]
end
```

Comment: You dropped the `"` after `:` in going from the regex to `match = ...`.  This will self-destruct--no thx reqd.

Comment: You'll also want to make `.*` non-greedy by adding a `?`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is:

```
s[/"start":"(.*?)"/, 1]
#=> "Desired Info"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(?:\\"start\\":\\")(.+)(?:\\")
```

"Desired Info" into the NON IGNORED capturing group.